# absolute root url css

Tags: html, css

I need to use this image from Images folder.
I use it in Content/style.css

url('background.jpg')

it shows me following error: http://localhost:50260/Content/Images/background.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript/ CSS/ Image reference paths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374305/javascript-css-image-reference-paths)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

background: url('../images/background.jpg');

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little hard to understand. If you want to reference a image using the root, then something like this will work:

```
background: url('/images/background.jpg');
```

The / at the start of the url says to reference the root.